# java.nio.file.FileSystemException: The file or directory is not a reparse point

Tags: java, linux, symlink

I am trying to create symlink in java between two files in a network drive. (I have full access to the drives). I am running this java program in my local machine (Windows) and the filesystem is on Linux. 
When I run the following code,

Files.createSymbolicLink(new File(destinationPath + fileName).toPath(), new File(thumbNailsSourcePath  + fileName).toPath());

I get the following excepton on the destination folder
java.nio.file.FileSystemException: The file or directory is not a reparse point.

But, if I deploy the same java program to the same Linux server, then it creates symlinks successfully.

Please let me know if I can solve this issue. I would ideally like to have integration tests running without any problem in my local machine.

Comment: Not all remote file access protocols support the concept of symbolic links

Comment: @Ferrybig can you elaborate? Thanks.